# how do I call a class object that is initialised in __init__ method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an s3class which has an attribute `__s3` to which s3 access key pair is configured.

```
class s3class():
    def __init__(self, access, secret, bucket_name):
        self.__bucket = bucket_name
        self.__s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                                 self.__access,
                                 self.__secret)

import s3class

## do something here##
obj = s3class()
obj.__s3.download_file('prefix/filename.csv')
```

I want to call a boto3 specific method `download_file` using the __s3 object in another module, which imports s3class.
When I reference __s3 object as ob.__s3 , I am getting AttributeError that  object  __s3 not found.

Comment: Can you provide complete example along with any error messages?

Comment: I have added more details @Marcin

Comment: I've noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, but non-was accepted. If all the answers weren't useful, that's fine. But if the answers were helpful, their acceptance is not only a good practice, but it signals others in future with similar issues to solve their own issues. Also it reduces the amount of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If your module containing `s3class` class is called `s3class.py` then you need:

```
from s3class import s3class
```